# Why is Postgres CTE slower than subquery?

Tags: postgresql, performance, cte, query-performance

I have a somewhat involved query that splits strings and outputs each word as a record.

I did a quick test, one with a CTE and one with a subquery and was somewhat surprised to see that the CTE takes twice as long to execute.

Here is the gist of what the query does:

```
-- 1. translate matches characters from comment to given list (of symbols) and replaces them with commas.
-- 2. string_to_array splits string by comma and puts in an array
-- 3. unnest unpacks the array into rows
```

## Inline subquery

```
SELECT
    sub_query.word,
    sub_query._created_at
FROM 
(   SELECT unnest(string_to_array(translate(nps_reports.comment::text, ' ,.<>?/;:@#~[{]}=+-_)("*&^%$£!`\|}'::text, ',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,'::text), ','::text, ''::text)) AS word,
        nps_reports.comment,
        nps_reports._id,
        nps_reports._created_at
    FROM nps_reports
    WHERE nps_reports.comment::text <> 'undefined'::text
) sub_query 
WHERE sub_query.word IS NOT NULL AND NOT (sub_query.word IN ( SELECT stop_words.stop_word FROM stop_words))
ORDER BY sub_query._created_at DESC;
```

## CTE

```
WITH split AS
(
SELECT unnest(string_to_array(translate(nps_reports.comment::text, ' ,.<>?/;:@#~[{]}=+-_)("*&^%$£!`\|}'::text, ',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,'::text), ','::text, ''::text)) AS word,
    nps_reports.comment,
    nps_reports._id,
    nps_reports._created_at
FROM nps_reports
WHERE nps_reports.comment::text <> 'undefined'::text
)

SELECT
    split.word,
    split._created_at
FROM split
WHERE split.word IS NOT NULL AND NOT (split.word IN ( SELECT stop_words.stop_word FROM stop_words))
ORDER BY split._created_at DESC;
```

And here are the EXPLAINs for each:

## Subquery Explain

```
Sort  (cost=15921589.76..16082302.91 rows=64285258 width=40) (actual time=16299.150..17697.914 rows=4394788 loops=1)
  Sort Key: sub_query._created_at DESC
  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 116112kB
  Buffers: shared hit=22915 read=7627, temp read=34281 written=34281
  ->  Subquery Scan on sub_query  (cost=2.49..2311035.10 rows=64285258 width=40) (actual time=0.177..13274.895 rows=4394788 loops=1)
        Filter: ((sub_query.word IS NOT NULL) AND (NOT (hashed SubPlan 1)))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 3676303
        Buffers: shared hit=22915 read=7627
        ->  Seq Scan on nps_reports  (cost=0.00..695825.11 rows=129216600 width=88) (actual time=0.073..9781.244 rows=8071091 loops=1)
              Filter: ((comment)::text <> 'undefined'::text)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 844360
              Buffers: shared hit=22914 read=7627
        SubPlan 1
          ->  Seq Scan on stop_words  (cost=0.00..2.19 rows=119 width=4) (actual time=0.016..0.034 rows=119 loops=1)
                Buffers: shared hit=1
Planning time: 0.115 ms
Execution time: 18451.245 ms
```

## CTE Explain

```
Sort  (cost=17213755.76..17374468.91 rows=64285258 width=40) (actual time=44008.467..45508.786 rows=4394788 loops=1)
  Sort Key: split._created_at DESC
  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 116112kB
  Buffers: shared hit=23031 read=7531, temp read=34281 written=353942
  CTE split
    ->  Seq Scan on nps_reports  (cost=0.00..695825.11 rows=129216600 width=135) (actual time=0.057..10451.951 rows=8071091 loops=1)
          Filter: ((comment)::text <> 'undefined'::text)
          Rows Removed by Filter: 844360
          Buffers: shared hit=23027 read=7531
  ->  CTE Scan on split  (cost=2.49..2907375.99 rows=64285258 width=40) (actual time=0.162..37888.364 rows=4394788 loops=1)
        Filter: ((word IS NOT NULL) AND (NOT (hashed SubPlan 2)))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 3676303
        Buffers: shared hit=23028 read=7531, temp written=319661
        SubPlan 2
          ->  Seq Scan on stop_words  (cost=0.00..2.19 rows=119 width=4) (actual time=0.009..0.030 rows=119 loops=1)
                Buffers: shared hit=1
Planning time: 0.649 ms
Execution time: 46297.825 ms
```

Comment: no json please. just show the text plan.

Comment: @Petar check out the query in my example, tell me how it performs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CTE's in PostgreSQL are an [optimization fence.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/27425/2639) That means the query planner doesn't push optimizations across a CTE boundary.

- [Blog entry about this](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-ctes-are-optimization-fences/)

I think a lot of this is silly though you can just write it like this.. Here we use `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` rather than the complex wrapping and `NOT EXISTS` rather than `NOT IN`

```
SELECT word,
  _created_at
FROM nps_reports
CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(regexp_split_to_array(
  nps_reports.comment,
  '[^a-zA-Z0-9]+'
)) AS word
WHERE nps_reports.comment <> 'undefined'
  AND nps_reports.comment IS NOT NULL
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM stop_words
    WHERE stop_words.stop_word = word
  )
ORDER BY _created_at DESC;
```

All of that said, whatever you're doing seems to be reinventing FTS. So that's also a bad idea.

Comment: Execution times:  `Yours: 22640.389 ms`,  `Subquery: 18451.245 ms`, `CTE: 46297.825 ms`

Comment: @Petar are you just trying to split all strings by `[^a-zA-Z0-3]` (non-alphanumerics?)

Comment: @Petar try the updated query, that should be substantially faster.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think regex is the way to go - it is an expensive operation - the updated query took `43638.959 ms`. I am fairly confident that my original subquery is the optimal solution (apart from what FTS can offer).

Comment: This question was more towards CTE vs Subquery and I think you have answered it. For anyone that comes here looking for an optimum solution, see this question stackoverflow.com/questions/46687065/ And also see my answer below. I was able to reduce the whole operation to `10 secs`

Answer (score 1):

@Evan Carroll explained why the CTE takes longer but here is an improved query, that is faster than all solutions listed above.

See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46687065/) for more background.

```
-- create custom dict (you don't necessarily need to do this)
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY simple_with_stop_words (TEMPLATE = pg_catalog.simple, STOPWORDS = english);
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION public.simple_with_stop_words (COPY = pg_catalog.simple);
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION public.simple_with_stop_words ALTER MAPPING FOR asciiword WITH simple_with_stop_words;

-- the actual query

SELECT 
    token.word, 
    nps._created_at
FROM nps_reports nps CROSS JOIN LATERAL UNNEST(to_tsvector('simple_with_stop_words', nps.comment)) token(word)
WHERE nps.comment IS NOT NULL AND
      nps.comment <> 'undefined' AND
      nps.language = 'en-US';
```

This utilises PostgreSQL's `to_tsvector` function which does several things depending on the configuration given to it. If used with the `simple` dictionary, instead of the custom one I made, it will simply split any string into words.

I am also utilising a feature from Postgres 9.3+, the `LATERAL` keyword, which enables me to pass an argument from the left side of the join to the right side of the join, i.e.: I can pass the `comment` into `UNNEST`.

This takes about `10 seconds` to execute over the whole database. Compare to the previous fastest method (subquery), which took `18 seconds`.